# Sorting data from lists and grouping in a table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Four types of data need to be selected from the list and grouped in a table. The example of the XML input looks as follows:

```
<DIV>
  <ul>
    <li>fr0.1.1 : en1.1.1</li>
    <li>fr0.2.1 : en1.2.1</li>
    <li>fr0.4.1 : en1.3.1</li>
    <li>fr0.6.1 : en1.4.1</li>
    <li>fr0.5.1 : en1.5.1</li>
    <li>fr.0.7.1 : en1.5.1</li>
    <li>        : en1.6.1</li>
  </ul
</DIV>
```

The 2nd digit in each 3-digit number having the same prefix (e.g. ‘fr’) is relative to the 2nd digit of the preceding and following 3-digit number, e.g. fr0.1.1, fr0.2.1, fr0.3.1 is a continuous sequence in this context, while fr0.1.1, fr0.3.1, fr0.2.1 OR fr0.1.1, fr0.3.1 are discontinuous.

I need a code that would find gaps and discrepancies in these relations only among the numbers prefixed with ‘fr’ on the left side of each <li> element. If there is a number missing in such a sequence, the code needs to retrieve it and list it in the first column named ‘Absent(fr)’. If the 2nd digits do not arrange in the growing order as you go down the list of all the 3-digit numbers on the left, the code should identify the number whose 2nd digit is a discrepancy in the sequence of growing order, e.g. it’s fr0.6.1 in the input example above for (0.)4(.1)<(0.)6(.1)>(0.)5(.1). If such number is found, it should be listed in the 2nd column called ‘Discrepant'. The third column should list the number with which the discrepant number matches on its right.

The fourth column called ‘No-match(en)’  should list the numbers prefixed with ’en’ if only they do not have a match prefixed with ‘fr’ on their right. In the example such a number is 1.6.1.

The fifth column colled ‘Repetition’ should list the number prefixed with ‘en’ if only it occur more than once in the input list. And the code should retrieve the matches prefixed with ‘fr’ for the repetitive number and  list it in the last column ‘Matches’.

The table in HTML output should look something as this (style such as color or bold are not important!):

[image: Table]

The xml output would look as this:

```
<table>
 <tr>   
   <th>Absent(en)</th>
   <th>Discrepant</th>
   <th>Match</th>
   <th>No-match(en)</th>
   <th>Repetition</th>
  <th>Matches</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>0.3.1</td>
   <td>0.6.1</td>
   <td>1.4.1</td>
   <td>1.6.1</td>
   <td>1.5.1</td>
   <td>0.5.1, 0.7.1</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Also, please share the HTML code that you expect for the table (colour codes included).

Comment: Note that if your answer is XSLT 1.0, would you consider the option of using the Saxon-CE javascript library, so that you could then leverage XSLT 2.0 in your solution? Distribution of Saxon-CE is governed by an MPL 2.0 license.

Comment: @Sean, I've just started using xslt 2.0 which is validated by Saxon-PE 9.something. I work on Oxygen 12.1. Pls see my question where I added the xml output code to give you a better idea what result I expect. Pls ignore the colors or bold in the visual, they are not important at all, just used to keep the breakdown clear.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your whole question. It is a bit too much for StackOverflow. What I will do is answer a core part of your question (first column). This should be enough to extrapolate from to get a full answer. If you are having problems extrapolating from my answer, then subdivide the unresolved parts of your problem into smaller tasks and post a separate SO question on each, of course, after you have had a good attempt at it yourself.

**This input document ...** (slightly different than yours to correct formation errors and not dealing with the case of the last li)

```
<DIV>
  <ul>
    <li>fr0.1.1 : en1.1.1</li>
    <li>fr0.2.1 : en1.2.1</li>
    <li>fr0.4.1 : en1.3.1</li>
    <li>fr0.6.1 : en1.4.1</li>
    <li>fr0.5.1 : en1.5.1</li>
    <li>fr0.7.1 : en1.5.1</li>
  </ul>
</DIV>
```

**... when applied to this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776650"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn so">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:function name="so:middle-number" as="xs:integer">
 <xsl:param name="dotted-text" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:sequence select="fn:replace( $dotted-text, 'fr0\.(\d+)\.1.*', '$1') cast as xs:integer" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:delta" as="xs:integer">
 <!-- Difference between this node and the previous.
      Count the first node as having difference = 1 . -->
 <xsl:param name="li" as="element()" />
 <xsl:sequence select="
   if ($li/preceding-sibling::li) then
       so:middle-number($li/text()) - so:middle-number($li/preceding-sibling::li[1]/text())
     else
       1" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:in-between" as="xs:integer*">
 <xsl:param name="lower-bound" as="xs:integer" />
 <xsl:param name="upper-bound" as="xs:integer" />
 <xsl:variable name="diff" select="$upper-bound - $lower-bound" />
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$diff eq 0"> 
    <xsl:sequence select="$lower-bound" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$diff eq 1"> 
    <xsl:sequence select="$lower-bound, $lower-bound+1" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="($diff ge 2)"> 
    <xsl:variable name="half-way" select="fn:round( $lower-bound + ($diff div 2))" />
    <xsl:sequence select="so:in-between($lower-bound, $half-way) , so:in-between( $half-way+1, $upper-bound)" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise />   
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/*/ul">
 <xsl:variable name="groups">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-adjacent="so:delta(.)">
   <so:group>
    <so:start><xsl:value-of select="so:middle-number( current-group()[1     ]/text())" /></so:start>
    <so:end>  <xsl:value-of select="so:middle-number( current-group()[last()]/text())" /> </so:end>
   </so:group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" /> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="so:group[1]" />

<xsl:template match="so:group">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="so:start/text() cast as xs:integer" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:variable name="prev" select="preceding-sibling::so:group[1]/so:end/text() cast as xs:integer" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:for-each select="for $x in so:in-between( $prev + 1, $this - 1) return $x">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="concat('0.',.,'.1')" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**... yields result ...**

```
<td>0.3.1</td>
<td>0.6.1</td>
```

.. which is the two absent li values.

### Take-home point

You can use the xsl:for-each-group/@group-adjacent instruction, grouping on the delta between the value of one li node and its predecessor. This gives you groups of sequential nodes. So just span the difference between the end of one group and the start of the next, and you have all the absent values. This gives you your first column.

Use similar techniques for the other columns.

---

### Update

I just realised that you don't need the so:inbetween() function. You can simply use the `to` operator. Sorry about that. Changing to the `to` operator should greatly simplify the stylesheet.

---

### Update 2

Here is the `to` version ...
I think it is satisfactorily small!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776650"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn so">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:function name="so:middle-number" as="xs:integer">
 <xsl:param name="dotted-text" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:sequence select="fn:replace( $dotted-text, 'fr0\.(\d+)\.1.*', '$1') cast as xs:integer" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:delta" as="xs:integer">
 <!-- Difference between this node and the previous.
      Count the first node as having difference = 1 . -->
 <xsl:param name="li" as="element()" />
 <xsl:sequence select="
   if ($li/preceding-sibling::li) then
       so:middle-number($li/text()) - so:middle-number($li/preceding-sibling::li[1]/text())
     else
       1" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/*/ul">
 <xsl:variable name="groups">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-adjacent="so:delta(.)">
   <so:group>
    <so:start><xsl:value-of select="so:middle-number( current-group()[1     ]/text())" /></so:start>
    <so:end>  <xsl:value-of select="so:middle-number( current-group()[last()]/text())" /> </so:end>
   </so:group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups" /> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="so:group[1]" />

<xsl:template match="so:group">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="so:start/text() cast as xs:integer" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:variable name="prev" select="preceding-sibling::so:group[1]/so:end/text() cast as xs:integer" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:for-each select="for $x in $prev + 1 to $this - 1 return $x">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="concat('0.',.,'.1')" /></td>
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### About XSLT being too hard

In reference to your comment about XSLT being too much to get your head around: Please remember that XSLT is just like any other language. You cant expect to pick up a language just by posting one or two questions on StackOverflow. I suspect that in the long run, your interests would be best served by an investment. Pick up a good book on XSLT 2 and read it. It is actually a surprisingly easy language to learn if you pick the right book. That is what I did, and I have found that the return on my investment was ample.

Comment: thank you for the code. Re to operator, do you mean this: op:to($firstval as xs:integer, $lastval as xs:integer) as xs:integer? And yet I know a way too little of XQuery and XPath fn and op so there are miles for me to go before I get my head around your code. I'm afraid it will be of little use for me at this stage. I reckon I'll have to find a simplier, yet probably more expensive, way to deal with my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I do not understand why you insinuate that I "expect to pick up a language just by posting one or two questions on StackOverflow". I'm just in a different place of knowing XSLT at this stage. Asking a question on StackOverflow should not imply that one does not read a book or two or three on XSLT. Having said that, I still see StackOverflow providing a good component of learning from, among other sources.